# Merging more than two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, panel

I am using `R` to merge more than two data frames. Each data frame corresponds to one year of observations and there is a column that uniquely identifies an employee. For example for two years I would observe:

```
 emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
                         "2015-03-27")),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 
  hours=c(100,56,34,65,38),
  
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# Print the data frame.         
print(emp.data)
```

[image](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)

and:

```
 emp.data2 <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (2:6), 
  emp_name = c("Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary","Zack"),
  start_date = as.Date(c( "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11","2014-02-11",
                         "2015-03-27")),
  salary = c(515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25,10), 
  hours=c(56,34,65,38,9),
  
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# Print the data frame.         
print(emp.data2)
```

[image]

Notice that I am essentially dealing with an **unbalanced panel**: columns across the years are the same, however the number of observations may vary across the years.

Essentially, I would like to merge around 10 of these data frames into one, I have tried using the function `merge()` in the following way:

```
merge(emp.data,emp.data2,by = "emp_id",all.x = TRUE,all.y = TRUE)
```

however it makes dimensions of the data frame increase proportionally to the amount of data frames merged since is gives me the output columns: `hours.x hours.y`, for example. This is clearly very inefficient since only one of those duplicate columns would have non-NA values. So essentially I am looking for a way to merge these data frames while keeping the columns constant and adding a year variable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
## Put the data frames in a list:
list_of_data = list(emp.data, emp.data.2, emp.data.3, ...)
## alternately, do this programmatically, maybe
# list_of_data = mget(ls(pattern = emp.data.*))

## Name the list with the years
names(list_of_data) = c(1996, 2014, 1066, ...)

## Combine it 
library(dplyr)
big_data = bind_rows(list_of_data, .id = "year")
```

For more details on this, see my answer at the FAQ [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207).

Comment: That works great, thanks. An additional question. Do you have a suggestion on how to deal with cases in which columns may change over time? Some might disappear and some may appear, for instance.

Comment: This method will still work - you'll just get missing values in the years they aren't present.